# Why does FILE_APPEND give me an error file not found, but "true" works fine but does not append

Tags: php, json

here is my code snippet: I had to comment out the line with FILE_APPEND.
I don't understand what is going on. especially since when I use the FILE_APPEND, it get a file not found error.

```
echo '<br />';
$rssrecord = json_encode($rss);
var_dump($rssrecord);

// Update the Rss feed file
require_once('/appconfig.php');

$app = new pathConfig;
$filePath = $app->getPath(); // Set Getter
var_dump($filePath); // outputs all paths
echo "<br><br>";
$jsonPath = $filePath['json']; // Getter for json
echo $jsonPath;
$rssFile = "rss.json";
$putfile = ($jsonPath.$rssFile);
echo '<br />';
echo $putfile;
//file_put_contents($putfile, $rssrecord.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($putfile, $rssrecord.PHP_EOL, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

this issue was a "permissions" issue. I checked the file properties and the security and realized I did NOT have read/write authority, nor could I grant myself the authority. I did then create a file in another path and it worked perfectly.

Comment: So weird... Well, mark this answer as "Accepted answer".